# Full Web Page Won't Save

Tags: windows

In firefox I am going to file  > save page as > web page (complete) but because the web page itself uses lazy loading, not all of the page content is saved in the html file.

Is there a way to get around this? I have tried a ton of image crawlers/downloaders/spiders/scrapers but they have the same problem as above.

I have tried command prompt scripting with wget.exe but despite it working on some web pages, does not work on this web page or one like it (in the same domain).

Comment: Welcome aboard, Kate. If you are looking for an app or plugin to help you, please ask us at [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). If you just want to do it with the browser itself, then this is the best site to ask.